# Button border with corner radius in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set a rounded border to a button but the border of the button is not correct.

Code:

```
Button(action: {
        print("sign up bin tapped")          
}) {
    Text("SIGN UP")
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
      .font(.system(size: 18))
      .padding()
      .foregroundColor(.white)
 }
  .border(Color.white, width: 2)
  .cornerRadius(25)
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the border at corner are cut-off.

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-border/ you can try this as your reference :)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Instead of setting the cornerRadius to the Button use an overlay for the inside View:

Edit: If you have a background for the button you also need to apply the cornerRadius to the background.

```
    Button(action: {
        print("sign up bin tapped")
    }) {
        Text("SIGN UP")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .font(.system(size: 18))
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
        )
    }
    .background(Color.yellow) // If you have this
    .cornerRadius(25)         // You also need the cornerRadius here
```

Comment: When I use your code, text inside button is hidden.

Comment: I am not sure but: Is it because i set the font to green and your background is green?

Comment: @Mahendra I edited my answer with the correct colors.

Comment: If we add background color to this button then will show a rectangle also whose corners are not round.

Comment: Does not work if we add background color.

Comment: The text will be hidden. Use 'background' instead of 'overlay'. Also use foregroundColor to RoundedRectangle for button background.

Comment: If you have a background color, after applying this suggested overlay, you can still apply a cornerRadius after that and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: Not a good implementation, if you notice the border is less than 2.

Answer (score 43):

## Updated for Swift 5 & iOS 13.4+ with Press States!

None of the examples worked for buttons with both dark and white background colors as well as none of them had press state updates, so I built this `LargeButton` view that you can see below. Hope this helps, should be pretty simple to use!

### Example Photos

[image]

### Example Use

```
// White button with green border.
LargeButton(title: "Invite a Friend", 
            backgroundColor: Color.white, 
            foregroundColor: Color.green) {
                        print("Hello World")
                    }

// Yellow button without a border
LargeButton(title: "Invite a Friend", 
            backgroundColor: Color.yellow) {
                        print("Hello World")
                    }
```

### Code

```
struct LargeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let foregroundColor: Color
    let isDisabled: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        let currentForegroundColor = isDisabled || configuration.isPressed ? foregroundColor.opacity(0.3) : foregroundColor
        return configuration.label
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(currentForegroundColor)
            .background(isDisabled || configuration.isPressed ? backgroundColor.opacity(0.3) : backgroundColor)
            // This is the key part, we are using both an overlay as well as cornerRadius
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .stroke(currentForegroundColor, lineWidth: 1)
        )
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
            .font(Font.system(size: 19, weight: .semibold))
    }
}

struct LargeButton: View {
    
    private static let buttonHorizontalMargins: CGFloat = 20
    
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    
    private let title: String
    private let action: () -> Void
    
    // It would be nice to make this into a binding.
    private let disabled: Bool
    
    init(title: String,
         disabled: Bool = false,
         backgroundColor: Color = Color.green,
         foregroundColor: Color = Color.white,
         action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
        self.disabled = disabled
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: LargeButton.buttonHorizontalMargins)
            Button(action:self.action) {
                Text(self.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            }
            .buttonStyle(LargeButtonStyle(backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                                          foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
                                          isDisabled: disabled))
                .disabled(self.disabled)
            Spacer(minLength: LargeButton.buttonHorizontalMargins)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Apply both `.cornerRadius(6)` and `.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))` works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

## Official `.bordered` modifier support in iOS 15+

`Button`s now have baked in border styling support using the `.buttonStyle(.bordered)` modifier. I would suggest using the corner radius Apple provides for these buttons for the best platform-specific styling. We can change the color to be consistent with the system styles for buttons and tint the background as well as text using the `.tint` modifier:

```
Button("Add") { ... }
.buttonStyle(.bordered)
.tint(.green)
```

[image: Green Tint Buttons]

You can make the tint color more prominent (bolder) using `.borderedProminent` and control the size using `.controlSize`:

```
Button("food") { ... }
.tint(.red)
.controlSize(.small) // .large, .medium or .small
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

[image: Small buttons]

You can also use this modifier on parent `View`s of `Button`s and toggle lighter color schemes using `.accentColor` in child `Button`s:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        Button("Test Button 1") { ... }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction) // Tapping `Return` key actions this button

        Button("Test Button 2") { ... }
        .tint(.accentColor)
    }
}
.buttonStyle(.bordered)
.controlSize(.large)
```

[image: Large Button Style]

### Advice

Apple for some reason doesn't like single-line bordered buttons which is why the `.border()` modifier was deprecated in Xcode 12. With this change, I suggest developers avoid creating single-line bordered buttons because they now are not preferred in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. Using prominent buttons everywhere also violates HIG.

<sub>Extra NOTE: Apple's `.bordered` style provides the standard platform style across device types. In addition, the `Button` responds to Dark Mode dynamically and scales its size with Dynamic Type (native accessibility support).</sub>

Comment: `.controlProminence(.increased)` has been deprecated in favor of `.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)`. https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/xcode-13-beta-4/

Answer (score 13):

Just add the `cornerRadius` argument:

```
.border(Color.white, width: 2, cornerRadius: 25)
```

---

using this simple **extension**:

```
extension View {
    func border(_ color: Color, width: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> some View {
        overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius).stroke(color, lineWidth: width))
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Does not work for me on macOS, error "Extra argument 'cornerRadius' in call", so the parameter is not available

Comment: Did you implement the `extension` first? @trinity420

Comment: No, I am new to Swift and oversaw this, thank you! Will try again.

Answer (score 13):

**iOS 15 or newer**
You can use Button properties for example

```
       Button(action: {
            //define action
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.circle.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
            Text("Restart")
                .font(.system(.title2))
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
        .controlSize(.large)
```

[image]

```
        .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle) //change bordershape see below
```

[image]

```
        .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle(radius: 4)) // see below
```

[image]

similarly you can change the **buttonSytle** and **controlSize**

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5 & iOS 14 – Borders also react when pressed**

```
struct PrimaryButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(5)
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red.opacity(0.5) : .red)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red.opacity(0.5) : .red, lineWidth: 1.5)
            )
     }
}
```

**How to use**

```
Button("Hide") {
    print("tapped")
}.buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
```

[borders also react when pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i47sB.png)

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 11.4.1

```
                            Button(action: self.action) {
                                Text("Button Name")
                                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding(10)
                                    .background(Color.darkGray)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

There isn't a need to add an overlay. You can substitute padding modifier with frame modifier. The action is a non return method outside of the body variable.

Right specifically for @MinonWeerasinghe:

```
Button(action: self.action) {
            Text("Button Name")
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(10)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke().foregroundColor(Color.red))
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: Where's the border?

Comment: Question is related to adding a border, but there is no code that does that in this solution.

Comment: @MinonWeerasinghe as per your comment answer updated

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            HStack {
            Button(action: {
                    print("sign up bin tapped")
            }){
                HStack {
                    Text("SIGN UP")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                    }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                )

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also did not set the maxWidth to .infinity because it means the button will fill the width of your container view.

The result will be :

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

**SwiftUI** :- You can also try this!

Currently I added check on same button for different shapes. you can separate my code if you want.

```
 // Global declaration
        @State var isFollowed = false
        Button {
            // Toggle Your isFollowed with true and false
            isFollowed = true
        } label: {
            Text(isFollowed ? "Following" : "Follow")
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.custom(MyFont.GilroyBold, size: 13))
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(
                            cornerRadius: 20,
                            style: .continuous
                        )
                        .fill(isFollowed ? .red : .clear)
                        RoundedRectangle(
                            cornerRadius: 20,
                            style: .continuous
                        )
                        .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2)
                    }
                )
        }
```

**eg**. Like I need Follow and following button.
On Follow button I shown corner rounds and only border.
On Following button I shown corner rounds and background colour.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, It's easy to understand. Perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a need for an update on the answers because some of the good ones are using `.cornerRadius(radius: CGFloat)` view modifier and that'll be deprecated soon as Xcode mentions.

The suggestion is to use `.clipShape(..)`.

Here is how you can achieve rounded corners without using `.overlay` (this felt hacky to me back in the day as well) and `.cornerRadius(..)`:

```
Button {
    // button action
} label: {
    Text("BUTTON TITLE")
        .bold()
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
}
.background(Color.blue)
.foregroundColor(.white)
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
```

You can use other shape's other than `RoundedRectangle` as well of course. For example: `Circle()`.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

> This worked for me

```
Button(action: {
  print("Exit the onboarding")
}) {
HStack (spacing: 8) {
  Text("NEXT")
  .foregroundColor(Color("ColorAccentOppBlack"))
}
.padding(.horizontal, 16)
.padding(.vertical, 10)
.foregroundColor(Color("ColorYellowButton"))
.background(
   Capsule().strokeBorder(Color("ColorYellowButton"), lineWidth: 1.25)
 )
} 
.accentColor(Color("ColorYellowButton"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Capsule. This is built-in into SwiftUI. It takes care of rounded corners. Full implementation is here https://redflowerinc.com/how-to-implement-rounded-corners-for-buttons-in-swiftui/

```
public struct ButtonStyling : ButtonStyle {
    public var type: ButtonType
    public init(type: ButtonType = .light) {
        self.type = type
    }
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label.foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12,
                                   leading: 12,
                                   bottom: 12,
                                   trailing: 12))
               .background(AnyView(Capsule().fill(Color.purple)))
               .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Wonder how to add button border with color gradient and corner radius
Here's how..

```swift
  Button(action: {self.isCreateAccountTapped = true},label: {Text("Create an Account")
.foregroundColor(Color("TextThemeColor36"))}
 )
.frame(height: 44)
.frame(width: 166)
.background(Color.clear)
.cornerRadius(8)
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
.stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("BtnGradientClr1"),Color("BtnGradientClr2"),Color("BtnGradientClr3")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)))
```