# Rounded corner border on a Button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have the following code:

```
private var googleButton: some View {
    Button {
        // Empty
    } label: {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
            Text("Continue with Google")
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(height: 35)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .tint(.white)
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    .controlSize(.regular)
}
```

Which produces this look:

[image]

How do I properly apply a border with the proper corner radius?

I have tried applying `.border`, etc.. to the button but it's all causing errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button border with corner radius in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928774/button-border-with-corner-radius-in-swift-ui)

Comment: I think you just want a proper way to set a border on a view (doesn't matter if it's a button or whatever), for that you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74613685/13728460) which will produce the result you want, but you may have to add corner radius to your button manually (to match the radius of the border)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Label if you want.

```
 Label("Continue with Google", systemImage: "heart")
            .padding()
            .background {
                Color.gray
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get this, how does this give me a border?

Comment: The background color will give grey background and then clipShape will cut the shape into rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like:

```
Button {
                print("example")
            } label: {
                HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                    Text("Continue with Google")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(height: 35)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .background(.white)
            .controlSize(.regular)
            .cornerRadius(5) // Have your custom value here
```